# How to filter records from a model within view?

Tags: python, django

I have a MyTab table in the model file as below:

```
class MyTab(models.Model):
    inserttime = models.DateTimeField(null=False, auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    total_clicks = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

And a view file as below:

```
def index(request):
    polls_list = Event.objects.all().order_by('-inserttime') # objective is to return records with iserttime > current time and in the order of ascending inserttime
    context = {'polls': polls_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)
```

How to rewrite my index() method to return only required records? I tried below options but I am not getting the right syntax. Thanks for any help.

```
polls_list = Event.objects.get(inserttime > timezone.now()).order_by('-inserttime')
polls_list = Event.objects.filter(inserttime > timezone.now()).order_by('-inserttime')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
polls_list = Event.objects.filter(inserttime__gt=timezone.now()).order_by('-inserttime')
```

For more info, please read [Django's Queryset API reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups).

Comment: is it possible to sort it in the opposite way? that is descending order?

Comment: You could use `order_by`.

Comment: The order could easily be changed by adding/removing `-` at the start of the field name. Please refer to the documentation. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by